# http://localhost:8080/jenkins shows 404

Tags: tomcat

i have just installed Jenkins & http://localhost:8080 worked fine, i could see the dashboard of the jenkins, next i followed [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_tomcat_setup). htm to setup tomcat, there was not issue in installing that but after that i am seeing 
HTTP Status 404 - /jenkins

> type Status report
>
> message /jenkins
>   description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11

so I am not sure what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Jenkins? Did you download the file or install it using the installer?

From the tutorial you listed it looks like it's using Tomcat to host the jenkins.war file, ie just copy the jenkins.war file into `<tomcat-location>/webapps` and it should be working assuming Tomcat is up and running. You can check `http://localhost:8080/manager/` for further information about what apps are running.

**EDIT**

To access the Tomcat manager you might have to add a role to your `<tomcat-location>/conf/tomcat-users.xml`file, like this:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager script" />
```

Comment: i did install by Java –jar Jenkins.war, i tried http://localhost:8080/manager/ its asking user name & password, i tried to look in to tomcat-users.xml but there is no password given.

Comment: So you started Jenkins at it own? Try shutting it down, then drop the `jenkins.war` file into tomcat webapps folder and start up tomcat. The problem might be that both Jenkins and Tomcat run on same port.

Comment: As for `username` and `password` you need to add a role to the tomcat file `<tomcat-folder>/conf/tomcat-users.xml` (See my **EDIT** in my answer). This is because Tomcat by default does not contain any user with the right role. See [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Answer (score 0):

i have uninstalled tomcat by doing C:> tomcat9 //DS//Tomcat9, re installed jenkins & after instillation i have given new admin password. my issue is resolved.
thanks everyone.